# Show a popup/message box from txt file content using mshta

Tags: vbscript, hta

Search around regarding mshta and found this example from the Internet but I'm not sure how to use it to read my text file content then show a msgbox from the txt file content

https://gist.github.com/simply-coded/4d80ce729c6cef8a860d466e8871323c

and here

https://forums.hak5.org/topic/41985-inline-vbs-scripting/

Text file at C:\List.txt
Contained

```
08Jan2019 : TOTAL $22.00 
14Jan2019 : TOTAL $101.00 
15Jan2019 : TOTAL $5.00 
16Jan2019 : TOTAL $12.00 
17Jan2019 : TOTAL $1.00
```

How can I implement mshta example from Github below to show a msgbox that contain text/string from my txt file?

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsh : Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'Message boxes that don't wait for a return to continue. No return values.
MsgBlank "tetttedghdhbcccc", "title"

'Functions for simple no wait message boxes without return values.
Function MsgBlank(m, t)
    wsh.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:Execute(MsgBox(""" & m _
        & """, vbOkOnly, """ & t & """)(window.close))"
End Function
```

Comment: Your question doesn't describe what problem you're facing. What do you expect the code to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: This code i use to open msgbox/a popup from a text file to view content inside. and it work perfectly (first code). While reading some article from internet saying that mshta also can be use to open msgbox. Then I do some digging and found second code which can create a popup too but example given only from pre defined text. But I want this code to read the content from my text file.

Comment: @amein What is the issue with the first code? Why do you need to run MsgBox via HTA? Why not just use MsgBox directly in VBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need HTA to show MsgBox without code execution interruption. More of that, passing a text or a file content within command line parameter breaks new line chars.

In the below example VBScript launches itself in another wscript.exe process to display `MsgBox`, passing the message text via process environment variable:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Check if the process launched for message output
ChkMsg

' Main code begins here
' ...
ShowMsg "Message doesn't interrupt code execution"
ShowMsg ReadTextFile("C:\List.txt", 0)
ShowMsg "Another one message"
' ...


Sub ShowMsg(sText)

    If sText = "" Then Exit Sub
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        .Environment("process").Item("msg") = sText
        .Run """" & WScript.FullName & """ """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """", , False
        .Environment("process").Item("msg") = ""
    End With

End Sub

Sub ChkMsg()

    Dim sText

    sText = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("process").Item("msg")
    If sText = "" Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox sText
    WScript.Quit

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, lFormat)

    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With

End Function
```

`MsgBox` can display a maximum of 1,023 characters, if you need more, then you may simply open a text file contents using standard Notepad:

```vb
sPath = "C:\List.txt"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe " & sPath, 0, True
```

BTW You may finally resort to dynamically created HTA if you need more complex GUI, like in [the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bvbscript%5d%208856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2%20is%3aanswer).

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: I think, i will go with the latter suggestion. Less headache with only open through notepad for now. Seems msgbox caused much trouble..haha. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said, this would be an example of what you are looking for:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsh : Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'Message boxes that don't wait for a return to continue. No return values.
Dim fso
Dim file
Dim content
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("c:\List.txt", 1)
content = file.ReadAll
file.Close
MsgInformation content, "title"
'Functions for simple no wait message boxes without return values.

Function MsgInformation(m, t)
    wsh.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:Execute(MsgBox("""&m&""",vbInformation,"""&t&""")(window.close))"
End Function
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm, weird. It is working in my machine, what error is throwing? or is it not the behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: When I doucble click, nothing come out. Any setting should i look for? Im using windows 10 laptop. When I run sample code from github, msgbox come out. https://i.imgur.com/2CRh44Q.gif